# How to make textblock move up (Float) with animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I would like to know how to make a textblock move up (or better to say float up) with animation in Xaml (WPF).

Let's say I have **login screen** and I have two textblocks: Username and Password. When I click on the textblock (User name or Password) the textblock will move up (float up) with animation effect until the textblock will cross the border line of the box and then the textblock will stop moving. In the same animation, the font size of the text in the textblock Become smaller (for example, from 12px to 6px).

And additionally, in the same animation, when the text moving up I want to add the blur effect to the text, the blur effect start when textblock floating up and return to normal when the textblock cross the line of the box.

[image: example of floating textblock]

In the end, when i click in somewhere else on the  Login screen the textblock will return to starting point position if nothing was writen in the box.

I found something similar [here](https://material.uplabs.com/posts/sign-in-label-transition-with-react)

this is my code (that doesn't work)
Xaml:

```
x:Class="tester.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tester"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="400" Width="600" >
<Grid>


     <Border Margin="246,164,184,175" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" >
            <Label
                Name="Two"
                Margin="-1,-11,61,-1"
                Width="100" Height="36" FontSize="20"  
                VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
                Foreground="Blue"  >                
                Name
                <Label.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="0" x:Name="BlurEffect2"/>
                </Label.Effect>
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger 
                        RoutedEvent="Label.MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="FirstLabelName" Completed="FirstLabelName_Completed" >
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Two"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Height)"
                                    To="20.0" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                    AutoReverse="False" />
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Two"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FontSize)"
                                    To="16" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                    AutoReverse="False" />
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="BlurEffect2"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius"
                                    To="10" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                    AutoReverse="False" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>                
            </Label>
        </Border>
        <Border Margin="0,0,20,50"  Height="30" Width="100" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="White"  >
            <Label
                Name="one"
                Margin="9,-1"
                Width="80" Height="30" FontSize="16" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                Foreground="Blue" Visibility="Hidden">
                Name
                <Label.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="10" x:Name="BlurEffect"/>
                </Label.Effect>

                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoardOne">
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="Effect1"  >
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="one"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Height)"
                                    To="30.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                    AutoReverse="False"  />
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="one"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FontSize)"
                                    To="12" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                    AutoReverse="False"  />
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="BlurEffect"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius"
                                    To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                    AutoReverse="False"  />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryBoardOne"></StopStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>                                    
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>               

            </Label>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Back:

```
private void FirstLabelName_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Two.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;            
            one.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried something or are you just sharing requirements? You could make a storyboard for the inline labels you want in Blend real quickly using the Storyboard tool to animate on focus state of a TextBox style template.

Comment: yes, I do have a code but it doesn't working

Answer (score 7):

So what you're looking for is loosely referred to as inline label inputs. They're not tough but if you want real slick ones it does take some effort into customizing control templates. You need to create your `Storyboard` animations and trigger them via enter/exit actions within your triggers. Unless you're using `VisualStateManager` in which case you would trigger the animations via `VisualState` instead.

Here's a quick PoC example of how you could do something like that to get you started. However I did purposely leave some finishing touches out to avoid just handing a full solution over. Except there should be enough for a quick completion and tuning to fit your needs. Hope this helps, cheers!

The result (in the form of a choppy .gif for visual aid);

[image]

...and here's the quick sample made from a default wpf `TextBox` template.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <Style x:Key="CW-Inline-TextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,25,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="CW-Inline-input-example">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="-6.667">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="-25.733">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="#FF0285BA"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontWeight)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <Grid>

                            <Border x:Name="border" Grid.Row="1"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" 
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                            </Border>

                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,0"
                                   Foreground="Gray" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>

                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>

                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CW-Inline-input-example}" />
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <!--
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                // In case you wanted to do something cool on exit too..
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            -->
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <TextBox Tag="Your label"
             Height="35" Width="150" FontSize="20"
             Style="{DynamicResource CW-Inline-TextBox}"/>

    <TextBox Tag="Your other label"
             Style="{DynamicResource CW-Inline-TextBox}"/>

    <TextBox Tag="Another Instance"
             Height="75" Width="150" FontSize="15"
             Style="{DynamicResource CW-Inline-TextBox}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

And sorry I couldn't respond sooner, been busy. Enjoy :)